# Avoiding 'MySQL server has gone away' and 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am getting the above errors.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError)
(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') 

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) 
(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

we are using a lot of ORM queries, but we use the same connection/session and if one orm throws error the other fails due to invalid trx rollback error. Is it recommended to use each connection/session for each orm query??????

I am getting this error in sqlalchemy NOT flask-sqlalchemy and also our application runs as a gunicorn server, it is a flask application. The application runs under app factory.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `max_allowed_packet` or `net_read_timeout` in your MySQL configuration file. Or run the following queries:

`SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=268435456;`

`SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout = 1000;`

To Modify the MySQL Configuration check [Setting max_allowed_packet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-6323/gicxk/index.html).